# Using elasticsearch completion Suggesters crashes our nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest, search-suggestion

We implemented an autocomplete feature using ElasticSearch Suggesters and we are facing crashes on very common phrases like "best", "the", even "iphone".

I read that it's memory hungry and goes quickly out of heap space. We are looking into how to set our cluster, or index our documents.

```
"mappings": { 
    "type": { 
      "properties": { 
        "keyword": { 
          "type": "text", 
          "fields": { 
            "nomalized": { 
              "type": "keyword", 
              "normalizer": "my_normalizer", 
              "ignore_above": 256 
            },  
            "completion": { 
              "type": "completion" 
            } 
          } 
        }
```

We have 1.3bn documents, each document contains a search `keyword` and 3 numeric metrics. We are doing the autocomplete feature on the `keyword` part.

We have 9 shards, each has around 12GB of contents. Our heap size is 32GB.
Sometimes the suggester works, but sometimes not on common words, and the issue is that it crashes our nodes. What options we have?

**update 1**

```
135G    data/nodes/0/indices/SJNHwqTQQquqj4CpfEsPkw
50G     data/nodes/0/indices/odTgqzEjRtCtTWyGkHb9kQ
56K     data/nodes/0/indices/JaEuh3z5SZmpg2-WBJrI8g
65G     data/nodes/0/indices/2BVVlEM5QxWk1aZK3Sud2A
249G    data/nodes/0/indices
```

**update 2**

cluster has been resized, upgraded each node to 39GB ram, 20GB set for heap size, after resize stats are here https://pastebin.com/EPhtEaY5

Comment: Can you update your question with the output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/stats`?

Comment: @Val when I did that it crashed the server, tried more than 10 times and once I got gateway timeout.

Comment: Do you have anything useful in the server log? Do you get a `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`?

Comment: I am looking into. Regarding stats, I stopped all requests, and ran the /_nodes/stats, and it times out in abou 30 seconds, but the heap space is constantly growing cerebro shows until it crashes. I am very curious why this stats crashes as well our cluster.

Comment: The node eventually crashes because the heap space keeps growing. Now if we figure out why the heap keeps growing, we might be able to pinpoint the underlying issue. Which version of ES are running by the way?

Comment: logs are available here, we are runnin 6.0.0 http://35.203.142.113/bnCluster.log

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your node doesn't have enough memory to load the Lucene data structures into memory, which makes sense if you have only 16GB heap allocated to ES (and thus a bit less than the remaining 16GB to Lucene). You should try to add another node(s) (scale horizontally), add more RAM (scale vertically) or downsize your index

Comment: how could I obtain the size of Lucene index? can I look at the size on the disk?

Comment: Try  `du -h $ES_HOME/data/nodes/0/indices/<index-id>`

Comment: isn't that disk size? I updated the question with the values.

Comment: You should try the three options I described in my comment above. Your cluster is probably undersized given the data you have.

Comment: @Val upgraded instances, I was able to obtain stats

Comment: Good, what story are they telling?

Comment: Check the link I am so new to EL that I don't know what to look for

Comment: Thanks, the nodes still crash after the upgrade?

Comment: I am still reindexing

Comment: @Val still crashes, I don't know what to do. I am wondering if soft sharding the index somehow into 3 pieceswould make sense, this was the last resort I wanted to take for an autocomplete feature. I think that some index doesn't fit into memory. also would shards number count? I have 9.

Comment: Can you provide the hardware specs of your nodes (cpu/cores, ram, disks, etc)?

Comment: @Val Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz, 6 vCPUs, 39 GB memory (20 allocated for heap), 500gb standard disk

Comment: @Pentium10 I am facing a similar problem. Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Vibin we experimented with a few normalizers that produced smaller indexes behind, but the general rule was that we increased the number of machines to support the operation.